# How to copy specific files into specific folder linux bash

Tags: linux, bash

> 1. Create 50 files whose names are from `1` to `50`.
> 2. Create five folders (`0`, `10`, `20`, `30`, `40`).
> 3. Copy those 50 files into folders based on their name (for example, file `21` will go to folder `20`).

I have created those files and folders, but have no idea how to move a specific file to specific folder. I tried writing

```
cp {1..9} /home/user/folder
```

but that's not acceptable. Is it possible to do using `if` and `elif`?

Comment: I'd use a simple `for` loop itc - but you can do without of course, but no need for `if` and `elif` as i see it

Comment: and in what folder should the file 50 go? in 40?

Comment: for i in {1..50}
do
if [ i -lt10 ] 
then
cp $i.txt 0

Is it possible like  this?

Comment: @DžiugasKubilinskas no its `for i in {1..50}` - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
cp {1..9} /home/user/folder
```

That will work, except you should specify the right folder to copy to. Perhaps you meant one of these?

```
cp {1..9} /home/user/folder/0
cp {1..9} 0
```

Another way is to use wildcards. `*` matches any string and `?` matches any one character. `2?` will match the file names `20` through `29`, for instance.

Comment: like this? : cp {2?} im only a begineer... :(

Answer (score 0):

When you don't mind using a `for` loop instead of `if` and `else` you could use code like this:

```
#1
touch file{1..50}
#2
mkdir dir{0..40..10}
#3
for i in {1..4}; do
  cp file${i}* dir${i}
done
cp file* dir0 # note that this will copy file50 into dir0
```